# SQL Joins vs Java code?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jooq

I have a query like this

```
Select Folder.name from FROM FolderTable,ValidFolder, ValidFolderGroup, ValidUser,
ValidLocation, ValidDepartment where  ValidUser.LocationCode *= ValidLocation.LocationCode         
    and ValidUser.DepartmentCode *= ValidDepartment.DepartmentCode and Folder.IssueUser =         
    ValidUser.UserId and ValidFolder.FolderType = Folder.FolderType and         
    ValidFolderGroup.FolderGroupCode = ValidFolder.FolderGroupCode and         
    ValidFolderGroup.GroupTypeCode = 13 and (ValidUser.UserId='User' OR             
    ValidUser.ManagerId='User')  and ValidFolderGroup.GroupTypeCode = 13 and             
    Folder.IssueUser = 'User'
```

Now here all the table which start with `Valid` are cache table so these table already contains data .

Suppose if someone using **JOOQ** or **Hibernate** which one will be the best option

1. Use query as written above with all Joins?
2. Or Use Java code to fulfill the requirement rather than join because as user using `Hibernate` or `JOOQ` it already have Java class for the table and `Valid` table have already all the data  ?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. What do you mean by "use Java"?

Comment: I mean to say about Java code is that as Valid table already cache the data so instance of these table java class already contain all the data of that table so rather adding valid table into where  condition i can first get all the record from Folder table and then in Java for loop i can satisfy the condition and create a list

Comment: What are you using as a cache mechanism? If you're just loading the entire `Valid` table into memory, I will almost guarantee you that this is a bad solution. For any problem.

Comment: Valid tables have only few records like 10-20 records only

Comment: How do you know? What mechanism do you have that enforces this?

Comment: Valid tables for some common data

Comment: So do you truncate it regularly? I'm not sure I understand how (or even why) you would have a table that holds a limited amount of rows.

Comment: May be i will not explain you whole concept in Stackoverflow my project based on DB ,some of the configuration needed for default information to show when someone browse the application

Comment: And we are using Ehcache for caching data into Valid tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### General answer:

Modern databases are incredibly good at optimising your query and choosing the best possible execution plan for you. Given your outer join notation using `*=`, you're obviously using SQL Server, so that's a pretty good database.

Even if you already have much of the *"Valid"* data in your application memory, chances are that your database also already has the same data in a buffer cache and thus the database doesn't need to hit the disk again for the various joins in your query.

In fact, depending on the nature of your data, the database might even assess that some of your joins are unneeded ([if you have the right meta data, like constraints](http://blog.jooq.org/2011/11/25/how-schema-meta-data-impacts-oracle-query-transformations/)).

#### Specific answer:

In your particular case, it *looks* as though you can indeed strip most of your query yourself and query only the `Folder` table using search criteria from your application's *"Valid"* cache. I'm saying that it *looks* like it, because I don't fully understand the business logic behind those joins and whether they're all modelling 1:1 relationships, or whether removing them will change the semantics of the query.

So, technically, it's possible that you can remove the joins, but if you want to stay on the safe side, just keep things as they are as you migrate to jOOQ or Hibernate.

#### Alternative 3:

Of course, instead of tampering with this query, you might even be able to remove this query and fetch the `Folder.name` property already in your previous queries when you load the *"Valid"* content into memory.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, you're probably not going to like this answer, but the best way to do this is not to keep `Valid` "cached".

The best solution in my opinion would be to use `jOOQ` (if you prefer DSL) or Hibernate (if you prefer OR mapping) and query the Database every time, and consistently use the DAO pattern.

The `jOOQ` and Hibernate guys are almost certainly better at SQL than you are. We've used `jOOQ` and Hibernate in really large enterprise projects, and they both perform exceptionally. Particularly with a good connection pool like `BoneCP`. If after you've got that setup running, and running well, but still think you may have performance issues, you can always add a cache (like `EhCache`) afterwards.

Ultimately tho', I'm making a lot of assumptions about your software, namely that

1. There are more people than you working on it, and
2. It has to be maintained. If neither of these assumptions are true, then you can safely disregard this answer.

Comment: hanks but i can not remove Valid table concept its base for application, in future we can remove but not now

Comment: I didn't say remove it. I said "don't store it in memory, fetch it from the database when you need it" alternatively if the data is static and immutable, don't store it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of views? Look into them, you'll be amazed.
Apart from that, it's impossible to say what you should do, there's no "best" and you provide way too little information to even make an educated guess about your specific requirements.

But, I'd not hard code things like database IDs in a query that ends up inside any program, far too prone to cause problems in the (near) future.